# Como executar comandos de teclas no Visual Basic (VBS) de forma temporizada, um comando cada intervalo de tempo?

Tags: windows, macro, vbs

Como fazer com que o envio das teclas <kbd>ALT</kbd> e <kbd>TAB</kbd> em [vbs](/questions/tagged/vbs) aconteça conjuntamente e operando esse envio com intervalos de pausa?

```
Set wshShell=wscript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
wscript.Sleep 300
wshShell.sendkeys "%{Tab 3}"
```

Comment: Eu consegui o efeito que estou procurando com o aplicativo grátis https://baixe.net/reckey , no entanto diretamente com um arquivo vbs ainda não consegui!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```bat
Dim Keys(4)
Keys(0)="^%{TAB}" 'enviar Alt + TAB
Keys(1)="^%{TAB}"
Keys(2)="^%{TAB}"
Keys(3)="{ENTER}" 

Set wshShell=wscript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
wshShell.AppActivate "chrome" 'Nome da Janela/Programa 
                              'Para o Envio das Teclas
                              'Se necessário! 

wscript.Sleep 500 'milissegundos 

For Each x In Keys
  wshShell.SendKeys x 'Variavel(x=index)
  Wscript.Sleep 500   
Next
```

Não há necessidade de usar recursos externos para funções disponíveis em [vbs](/questions/tagged/vbs).

**[Índice de A a Z para ajuda on-line VBS /En](https://ss64.com/vb/)**
***[Para especificar caracteres que não são exibidos ao pressionar uma tecla, como ENTER ou TAB, e teclas que representam ações e não caracteres, use os códigos da tabela a seguir:`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/sendkeys-statement)***

Comment: não funcionou, eu precisava que fosse executado ALT+TAB, espera um tempo, solta somente o TAB  ainda com o ALT pressionado, pressiona o TAB de novo, espera um tempo, e assim por diante, acada intervalo de tempo vai soltado e pressionando somente o TAB sempre com o ALT pressionado, entendeu?

Comment: `Alt + TAB` == [`("%{TAB}")`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18666468/how-do-i-sendkeys-an-alt-tab) O uso no código do `%+A` é um exemplo para uso com letra, para outras teclas use [`{nome da tecla}`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/sendkeys-statement)

Comment: Como eu já disse, quando executa a pausa a tecla ALT é solta, o que foge do que eu preciso.

Comment: Agora caiu a ficha aqui! Use:  `^` + `%` + `{TAB}` == `"^%{TAB}"`

Comment: Agora sim teve o efeito que preciso, com o ^ (CRT) deu o mesmo efeito de fixar a tecla ALT (%), só faltou entrar na opção deseja que é quando agente solta a teclas alt e tab, neste caso, dando enter, conforme sugeri.  Valeu, obrigado!!

Answer (score -2):

Só consegui resolver sua questão com um driver (**nircmdc.exe**) (https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/nircmd-x64.zip). Usando o nircmdc na mesma pasta do seu codigo.vbs vai funcionar com você programando tudo em vbs.

```
Set wshShell=wscript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
wscript.Sleep 2000 
wshShell.Run "nircmdc.exe  sendkey alt down", 0, True
wscript.Sleep 2000
wshShell.Run "nircmdc.exe  sendkey tab press", 0, True
wscript.Sleep 2000
wshShell.Run "nircmdc.exe  sendkey tab press", 0, True
wscript.Sleep 2000
wshShell.Run "nircmdc.exe  sendkey alt up", 0, True
```

Comment: esta foi a melhor solução que encontrei

Comment: Funcionou direitinho. Otimo, isso resolveu meu problema, obrigado!

Comment: Quando descobrir como fazer sem necessidade do driver eu post aqui!